# dropdown list not populating with Ajax

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

Whilst I'm sure it must be something really obvious, I can't see where I am going wrong with this. I have a drop down list with two options in it. When I Select an option it should use XMLHttpRequest() to get a list of customers from the database, based on the option selected.

I have two parts:

ajax2_js.php - contains the javascript and html form.

ajax2_DBAccess.php - contains the PHP that gets the list from the databse.

I have checked everything on the second page, and this works fine on it's own (and displays the relevant list as a dropdown menu), but when I select the option on the first page, nothing happens.

My code thus far is:

ajax2_js.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <script>
function ajaxFunction()
{
var ajaxRequest;
ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
            {
                document.getElementById('customerDiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
            }
    }
ajaxResuest.open("GET", strURL, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
        </script>           
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="" name="form1">
        Network : <select name="network" onChange="ajaxFunction('ajax2_DBAccess.php?network='+this.value)">
            <option value="">Select Network</option>
            <option value="1">Net1</option>
            <option value="2">Net2</option>
         </select>
        </br>
        Customer : <div id="customerDiv">
            <select name="select">
                <option>Select Customer</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

ajax2_DBAccess.php

```
<?php
$network=$_GET['network'];
$q1 = "SELECT `CustName` FROM monitor.customers where network = $network;";

$con = new mysqli('localhost:3306', 'xxx', 'xxx');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        $error = mysqli_connect_error();
        echo $error;
        exit();
    }
else
    {   
        $ConfRes = mysqli_query($con, $q1); 
        if ($ConfRes)
            {
                echo "<select name=\"Customers\">";
                echo "<option>Select Customer</option>";
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ConfRes, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                    { 
                        $result = $row['CustName'];
                        echo "<option value>$result</option>";
                    };
                echo "</select>";
            }
        else
            {   
                $error = mysqli_error();
                echo $error;
                exit();
            }   
    };
?>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the value of `strURL` in `ajaxFunction`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the javascript error log.
This might be the problem, a spelling error in "Request".
ajaxResuest.open("GET", strURL, true);

Also, your SQL query suffers from an SQL injection vulnerability in the $network parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use XML or JSON to return list. This [tutorial](http://json.org/example.html) should help. I personally would use XML.

```
header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
  $newnode->setAttribute("CustName",$row['CustName']);
  } 

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

but there are plenty of tutorials on both methods.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help guys, I have tracked it down to three things (all my fault):

```
function ajaxFunction()
```

should be:

```
function ajaxFunction(strURL)
```

.

```
ajaxResuest.open("GET", strURL, true);
```

should be:

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", strURL, true);
```

.

and finally:

```
document.getElementById('customerDiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('customerDiv').innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

.

(and of course the SQL injection vulnerability mentioned above which I will also fix).

cheers.